# Jquery find() element by class then remove it

Tags: jquery, find

I have html in a var that I am trying to edit. I want to move the UL with class "files" to its own var then remove it from the data var.

I have this so far but doing it wrong. I cant seem to understand it.

```
var data = '<ul class="dirs"><li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Games/">Games</a></li><liclass="d"><a href="#" rel="/Log/">Log</a></li></ul><ul class="files"><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar.txt</a></li><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar2.txt</a></li></ul>';

var files = $(data).find("UL.files").html();
```

Expected Result:

```
data = '<ul class="dirs"><li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Games/">Games</a></li><li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Log/">Log</a></li></ul>';

files = '<ul class="files"><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar.txt</a></li><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar2.txt</a></li></ul>';
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is UL capitalized in `find("UL.files")`? Also, what behavior are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the string, but you can create new strings.

```
var data = '<ul class="dirs"><li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Games/">Games</a></li><liclass="d"><a href="#" rel="/Log/">Log</a></li></ul><ul class="files"><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar.txt</a></li><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar2.txt</a></li></ul>';

var ul1 = $(data).filter('ul')[0];
var ul2 = $(data).filter('ul')[1];

var files1 = ul1.outerHTML || $('<div>').append(ul1).html();
var files2 = ul2.outerHTML || $('<div>').append(ul2).html();
```

This places a new UL element into `ul1` and `ul2`. Then to get the `html` string, you use the `.outerHTML` property.

Because `Firefox` doesn't support `outerHTML`, you need a hack to make it browser compliant.

**Example output:** http://jsfiddle.net/bjgLV/

Answer (score 0):

I found that `$(data)` is not producing the whole html you wanted. Try running `$(data).html()`

The output: `"<li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Games/">Games</a></li><liclass="d"><a href="#" rel="/Log/">Log</a></liclass="d">"`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:http://jsfiddle.net/kcAn3/

the code that you had earlier dint pass the w3c validation scheme and I am guessing jquery accounts that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = '<ul class="dirs"><li class="d"><a href="#" rel="/Games/">Games</a></li><liclass="d"><a href="#" rel="/Log/">Log</a></li></ul><ul class="files"><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar.txt</a></li><li class="f"><a href="#">fubar2.txt</a></li></ul>';

var $uls = $(data).filter("ul").wrap("<div>");

data = $uls.first().parent().html();
file = $uls.last().parent().html();
```